# Improving my QZ-Algorithm (Include Shifts)

Tags: numerical-analysis, eigenvalues

I Need to to solve an generalized Eigenvalue Problem and to compare two Methods (QR and QZ) concerning their convergence rate and execution time.

I started with the Basic QR-Algorithm, implemented in Matlab, tested the results and in the last step i included double-shifts and Deflation strategies.

Now it is time to improve my QZ-Algorithm: I think ist way more complicated, as i did not find any QZ-Algorithm implementations in the Internet. So i grabed the paper of Moler and Stewart and wrote my own implementation. I've been very glad that i did manage to write an algorithm producing the correct results. To have a fair comparison i would like to enhance this algorithm as to include single/double shifts so i can compare the Performance between the QR- and QZ-Algorithm. I think the implicit shift should be more stable, but i want the fastest Solution (less iterations).

You can find the paper here: http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/746896.pdf
And an extensional paper here: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19730018792.pdf

This is my algorithm so far (works correctly, but without shifting, so it is quite slow):

```
function [lambda, iteration] = QZAlgo(A, B, precision, maxIterations, useHouseholder)   
    len = length(A);

    % 1. Step: Preparation of Matrices
    % Transform A to Hessenberg form and B to upper triangular form
    if (useHouseholder ~= 0)
        [Q, B] = TriangularFormByHouseholder(B);
    else
        [Q, B] = TriangularFormByGivens(B);
        Q = Q';
    end
    A = Q*A;
    [A, B] = HessenbergFormByGivensWhileMaintainingB(A, B);

    % 2. Step: QZ-Iteration
    for iteration=1:maxIterations      
        p = 1;
        S = A - p*B;

        if (useHouseholder ~= 0)
            [Q, R] = TriangularFormByHouseholder(S);
        else
            [Q, R] = TriangularFormByGivens(S);
            Q = Q';
        end

        B1 = Q*B;
        [B2, Z] = RepairTriangularFormByGivensFromRight(B1);

        B = Q*B*Z;
        A = Q*A*Z;

        lambda = diag(A) ./ diag(B);

        if (CheckForRequiredPrecision(A, B, precision))
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

The Triangular-Functions are basically QR-Decompositions. The HessenbergFormByGivensWhileMaintainingB-Function creates an QR-Decomposition of A while repairing changes of B with Givens-Transformations of the right side.

The Algorithm works so far, but is, as already mentioned, quite slow.

Do anybody know how i can implement some shifting-strategies to the algorithm?

ANY help, no matter of what Kind and no matter about which shifting strategy, is GREATLY appreciated. I will spend you a crate  of beer of your choice, if we can manage to get this working, if you like ;-)

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT: If you Need to have a look in some of the subfuctions, i can provide them here, too.

EDIT2: I tried to have a look at CLAPACK (http://www.netlib.org/clapack/) to figure it out, but the Code is so confusing to me that i had to give it up...

EDIT3: Some of my thoughts about the explicit shift

- Choose shift p: I've Chosen the element in the right bottom Corner of S=A-B as i thought it must be similiar to the procedure of the QR-Algorithm
- Calculate QR-Decomposition of A-p*B
- Calculate B'=Q*B*Z just the same way i did above
- Calculate A=SZ + p*B = Q(A-p*B) + p*B'
  But this Procedure did not work. I am clueless at this Point :-(

Answer (score -1):

Why don't your consider the "eigs", a built-in function in MATLAB ? Are your matrices nonsymmetric? If symmetric, maybe you can also choose FEAST solver or JDQR.m http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~vorst102/JDQR.html for solving your generalized eigenvalue problems.

Comment: I do not consider built-in functions of MATLAB, because i am going to implement that algorithm in C. So, i use MATLAB just for testing the correct functionality of the algorithm before i am starting the C implementation.

What kind of algorithm is JDQR?

If you consider the following generalized eigenvalue Problem $Ax = \lambda Bx$, thent $B$ is symmetric, but $A$ is not!

Comment: OK. Maybe, I suggest you look at ARPACK SOFTWARE: http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/. Besides, it seems that JDQR method can be available for nonsymmetric generalized eigenvalue problems. You can find some references in website http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~vorst102/JDQR.html

Comment: It is planned to implement that algorithm on an embedded Hardware so i am not interested in using an rather big library. So, it would like to take my QZ-Algorithm as a Basis for further improvements. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement shifts in the algorithm above?

Comment: It is pricy, but for an industrial production setting (vs. research or a one-time use), Mathworks does have the [Embedded Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/)